# 3 duvidas de post de novo usuario com spring boot

Tags: java, api, spring, rest

estou com a seguintes duvidas quando ao salvar um usuário em uma api usando spring boot.

1)A melhor forma de verificar se o email já existe é essa?

2)no caso eu estou enviando o id do usuário que acabou de ser salvo, mas ele não esta sendo enviado como json, só esta enviando o valor. Como que eu envio como json? obs: se eu enviar o usuário inteiro ele vai no formato json

3)como capturar um eventual erro ao salvar o usuario? para que eu possa trata-lo ou enviar um status de erro

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> novoUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario){
        //Se o email já existir eu retorno um status de erro
        if(usuarioRepository.findByEmail(usuario.getEmail()) != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
        }
        usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(usuario.getId(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Melhor forma é muito relativo. Existem **n** formas de se fazer isto, cada um com um propósito diferente. Se o que você fez te atende, mantenha da forma que está.

2 - Ele não está sendo serializado por se tratar de um valor simples. Você pode encapsular este id em um POJO para serializá-lo como json:

```
class Model {

    Long id;

    Model(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(new Model(usuario.getId()),HttpStatus.OK);
```

3 - Se vc quiser tratar os erros a nível de método, utilize um try/catch:

```
try {
    usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
} catch(Exception e) {
    // tratar excecao
}
```

Se vc quiser tratar os erros a nível de controller, utilize um método anotado com `@ExceptionHandler`:

```
public class FooController{

    //...
    @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class, CustomException2.class })
    public void handleException() {
        //
    }
}
```

Se vc quiser tratar os erros a nível de aplicação, utilize a anotação `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)  // 409
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

[Este artigo](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) do blog do Spring fala sobre o tratamendo de erros no framekwork.

Comment: Muito Obrigado mesmo, e obrigado por apresentar diversas formas de tratar o erro, vou estudar todas elas